Arithmetic on uintptr_t
During a code review, this function was being reviewed:
static inline bool is_aligned(const void *ptr, size_t byte_count)
{
    return (uintptr_t) ptr % byte_count == 0;
}

on which @Toby Speight said:

Any kind of object pointer can be converted to uintptr_t, but arithmetic on this integer is unspecified. This test might work on your platform, but there are systems (notably, ia32 segmented memory architectures) where it's likely to be incorrect.

In that case, what is the correct way to do this (find the remainder)?

Was there any rationale given? Where any examples given of it giving wrong results?

How about memcpy of ptr into an appropriate ineger type that can hold the address (e.g. uint64_t) and then do the arithmetics ?

@wohlstad pointer does not have to hold an physical address.

@UlrichEckhardt Toby didn't. Some other SO answers I was looking at did, because it doesn't have to hold "a physical address", or so they said.

@0___________ I didn't claim it must. But will it not work to memcpy ptr to a suitable integer type and do the arithmetic in order to determine alignment ? This will overcome what you about conversion to uintptr_t where the compiler is free to do anything. Am I wrong ?

I suspect that is_aligned will only ever be used to check for aligned to 2^n byte boundaries in which case I'd be more inclined to use an & mask and  0<n<65. Whilst it is true that in theory compilers are free to use segmented addresses or other means I haven't seen any pointers in that form for a very long time. Almost everything uses a flat memory model these days. Are there any major compilers or code generators out there still using segmented addressing even if their hardware permits it?

@wohlstad yes, you are wrong. What is stored in the pointer is only known to the implementation.

@MartinBrown compilers can do much more than just useing segments.  The standard does not cover it. The question is about portable way - and there no portable way of doing it

@0___________ can you cite any compiler in use today where that actually happens?

@MartinBrown portable code means what it means. No imlementation or not defined behavior

@Harith, do you need an alignment test that even when  byte_count is not a power-of-2?

@chux-ReinstateMonica I do not. They are all powers of 2.

@Harith Range? 1,2,4,8 up to what?

@chux-ReinstateMonica There's no upper limit. "alignment must be a power of 2" is all my allocator cares about.

@0___________ unless there is a compiler (in common use) where pointers are not amenable to having arithmetic done on them then it is de facto portable code for all practical purposes even if it is not strictly portable according to the standard. There has to be at least one platform where such non-portable code fails for it to be actually non-portable in practice. I guess some paged memory embedded systems might qualify but their C compilers are non compliant in other ways too. It deserves a note to the effect that it is using undefined implementation dependent behaviour but that's all.

@MartinBrown it does not matter. The code is portable or it is not. The code can't be partially portable

Arithmetic on unsigned integers is well-defined. The question is just what manner of value you get after conversion from a pointer. On mainstream systems this is unspectacular. This will even work fine on many small memory systems that use extended addressing beyond the address bus width. People on these sites are often too "language lawyerish" to give you meaningful information, often speaking of some fictional systems which they haven't worked with and which doesn't even exist.

@0___________ There's portability between different compilers to the same target. Or portability between different targets with the same core. And so on - of course there are different grades of portability. Why we shouldn't worry about portability to obsolete, exotic or fictional systems because that's a huge waste of everyone's time.

@0___________ It is de facto portable if no system exists (today) where it doesn't work!

Does this answer your question? Is there a failsafe way to determine the alignment/trailing bits of a pointer in C?

I don't think this is opinion-based. By correct, they clearly mean most portable, since the 'incorrect' approach raised concerns about portability. That being said, this is still probably a duplicate of the question I linked above.


In that case, what is the correct way to do this

There is no standard specified portable solution.
OP's approach is reasonable, yet lacks correctness with select implementations:

byte_count, when not a power-of-2, risks trouble when (uintptr_t) ptr is not a linear mapping of addresses such as DOS segment: offset.  (OP later reports that only power-of-2 values are used.)  It may also be a problem with large powers-of-2 on like systems.

uintptr_t is an optional type and when it does not exist, obviously code will not compile.  Alternatives include casting to size_t, uintmax_t - each with certain limitations.  I'd consider size_t (since byte_count is size_t, no need for a potential wider type) for this alignment test instead of uintptr_t for greatest portability.

Testing (to steer code compilation) if an implementation uses linear addressing is also a challenge.  I know of no universal test.




What is the correct way to do this ... ?

Usually the best alternative is to re-assess the need for the coding goal.  Why is this function needed?  Often the higher level goal can be achieved without this implementation specific code.

@Harith, for an alignment test of powers-of-2, return (uintptr_t) ptr % byte_count == 0; as return (size_t) ptr % byte_count == 0; affords greater portability with no loss of functionality.  Both will fail on some truly esoteric system, but the 2nd works when uintptr_t is not defined.

Why is this function needed? ==> Merely for unit-testing to see if my allocator is actually aligning the allocation requests correctly. Do you have an alternate solution I could use? (Good point about size_t, I'd replace uintptr_t with it).

@Harith So on an esoteric system where return (uintptr_t) ptr % byte_count == 0;  passes, the original allocation itself may still be amiss.  I suppose your "my allocator" is for some nuanced requirement, else one could use aligned_alloc(),

Well, fair enough.

The standard does not say how a pointer to void is converted to uintptr_t.

The following type designates an unsigned integer type with the
property that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type,
then converted back to pointer to void, and the result will compare
equal to the original pointer

You assume that uintptr_t after the conversion will represent the physical address. This assumption is wrong. The compiler is free to do anything during the conversion. Imagine an implementation which keeps all pointers in the internal array and uintptr_t will hold an index of this pointer in that array.

In that case, what is the correct way to do this (find the remainder)?

There is no portable way of doing it - you need to rely on your implementation - but it is not portable.

Then am I right to conclude that the answer to my question is, 'There is none'?

@Harith - To make an arena allocator, you have to make assumptions on the underlying memory model. One reasonable assumption is that the conversion works, If it fails on Windows-286, that might not be a problem.

@Harith in general - there is no way. Only implementation-specific way.
